# Elasticsearch scope nested aggregation to the query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a query of a nested datatype and want to return the stats aggregation for the nested datatype (filtered by the query). Here is the code:

```
    GET dan-created/_search
{
  "_source" : ["m_iID", "m_iYear"],
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "m_PeopleList",
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "m_PeopleList.name": "Daniel"
            }
         },
         "inner_hits" : {}
      }
   },
   "aggregations" : {
    "people" : {
        "nested" : {
          "path" : "m_PeopleList"
        },
        "aggregations" : {
          "averageDist": {
            "stats" : {
              "field":"m_PeopleList.value"
            }
          }
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

The stats returned are for the whole index, but I want them to only return for the matches from the query above. I have seen examples of this elsewhere but not with the latest version of elasticsearch and I can't seem to get them to work.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

```
"aggregations" : {
  "people" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "m_PeopleList"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "myFilter": {
          "filter" : { "match": { "m_PeopleList.name": "Daniel" } },
          "aggregations": {
            "averageDist": {
              "stats" : {
                "field":"m_PeopleList.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as I want. I would have thought there would be a way to do this without specifying the filter query twice. But I see that if you just want the aggregation you can remove the query section and add "size":0. Thanks!

Comment: Without `nested` document you could define the filter only once.
But as aggregations and query doesn't shared the same `nested` clause you have to define it twice (with size != 0)